# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr end template?

Tags: tables, longtable, multicolumn

I get the error mentioned in the title of the question.

```
\begin{table*}[!ht]
  \centering
    \caption{\textit{first scenario : heuristic methods}} \label{Table2}
    \resizebox{2\columnwidth}{!}{%

\begin{tabular}{|ccc||cccc||cccccccc|}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Instances}}
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Weekly Problem}}
&\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Daily Problem}}
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{} 
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\underline{Heuristic (WPA)}}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\underline{Heuristic (DPA)}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\underline{Large Neighborhood Search (LNS)}}
\\
Staff &Activities &Periods  &Workload  &Transport costs  &Time(s)    &Gap   &Total activities &Activities added  &Total cost  &Time(s)  &Gap  &Total cost  &Time(s)  &Gap \\ \hline
  3     &72         &10        &391       &2175            &5        &0\%         &90              &18                  &2425      &3600   &28\%    &3839      &2012     &21\% \\
  \hline
  3     &72         &10        &360       &2254            &2        &0\%         &90              &18                &2654      &3600   &36\%    &3095      &2000     &24\% \\
    \hline
  3     &72         &10        &402       &2147            &7        &0\%         &90                &18                &2887      &3600   &33\%    &3581      &2004     &22\% \\
    \hline
  5     &120        &10        &179       &2812            &2000     &1\%         &150             &30                  &4101      &3600   &59\%    &5194      &2000     &22\% \\
  \hline
  5     &120        &10        &359       &3432            &101      &5\%         &150             &30                  &5120      &3600   &44\%    &6646      &2005     &24\% \\
    \hline
  5     &120        &10        &285       &3409            &489      &7\%         &150             &30                  &4325      &3600   &34\%    &6156      &2001     &23\% \\
  \hline
  6     &140        &10        &137       &3384            &616      &13\%        &175             &35                  &6387      &3600   &70\%    &8382      &2000     &25\% \\
    \hline
    6     &140        &10        &240       &3145            &2000     &9\%           &175             &35                  &6175      &3600   &64\%    &8425      &2000     &21\% \\
    \hline
    6     &140        &10        &198       &3454            &1871     &12\%          &175             &35                  &6324      &3600   &57\%    &8642      &2000     &22\% \\
    \hline

\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table*}
```

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In the first row you're asking for 3+4+8+3+4+2+3+3=30 columns, that you don't have. Shouldn't be there a ``\\`` after “Daily Problems”? Also the following `&` should be removed.

Comment: I inserted the table entered in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to end the first row:

```
\begin{tabular}{|ccc||cccc||cccccccc|}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Instances}}
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Weekly Problem}}
&\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Daily Problem}}\\ % end of first row
\multicolumn{3}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\underline{Heuristic (WPA)}}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\underline{Heuristic (DPA)}} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\underline{Large Neighborhood Search (LNS)}}\\
```

Comment: Thank you. But, i want a table like my first table entered in Excel !

Comment: @user41096 That's a completely different question

Comment: Yes, can u help me Plz ?